# SMB connection fails - "Invalid response error: invalid negotiate flags"

Tags: windows, smb

I am getting below error while using the smbDialer.Dial():

```
"invalid response error: invalid negotiate flags\\ngoroutine 1
```

There is a github issue open for same with no response :
https://github.com/hirochachacha/go-smb2/issues/49

Anyone already solved or know how to get rid of this?